# Winforms background worker gets stuck

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I am trying to build a simple code that joins csv files into one distinct file, but my background worker seems to have a mind of its own and my code gets stuck every time.
Here is my code for joining the file using the background worker:

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(saveFilePath))
            {
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    btnBrowseSave.PerformClick();
                }));
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(saveFilePath))
            {
                if (dragEventArgs != null)
                    files = (string[])dragEventArgs.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

                int filesCount = 0, rowsCount = 0;
                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    filesCount++;
                    int fileTotalLines = File.ReadAllLines(file).Length;

                    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                    {
                        lblFileName.Text = "Loading file: " + file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                        lblTotalFiles.Text = "File " + filesCount + " of " + files.Length;
                    }));

                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(saveFilePath))
                        {
                            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    while (stopPosition > rowsCount)
                                    {
                                        reader.ReadLine();
                                        rowsCount++;
                                    }
                                    string email = reader.ReadLine().Trim();
                                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) && !dicEmails.ContainsKey(email))
                                    {
                                        dicEmails.Add(email, null);
                                        writer.WriteLine(email);
                                    }
                                    rowsCount++;
                                    stopPosition++;

                                    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress((rowsCount * 100 / fileTotalLines), (int)ProgressType.Row);
                                    if (backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
                                        return;
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    hadReadErrors = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0, (int)ProgressType.Row);
                    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress((filesCount * 100 / files.Length), (int)ProgressType.File);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            hadReadErrors = true;
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            backgroundWorker.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            switch ((int)e.UserState)
            {
                case (int)ProgressType.Row:
                    lblFileProgress.Text = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";
                    fileProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
                    break;
                case (int)ProgressType.File:
                    lblTotalProgress.Text = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";
                    totalProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
```

When I run in debug mode and go with the debugger I don't see any problems, but when I let the code run it self it gets stuck and crashes.
Can someone PLEASE help me and tell me what am I missing out here ?

Here is the exception:

```
Managed Debugging Assistant 'ContextSwitchDeadlock' has detected a problem in    
'C:\Users\Develop\Desktop\ExcelBuilder\ExcelBuilder\bin\Debug\ExcelBuilder.vshost.exe'.

Additional information: The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0x90fb78 
to COM context 0x90fc30 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination
context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very 
long running operation without pumping Windows messages. This situation generally has 
a negative performance impact and may even lead to the application becoming non 
responsive or memory usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, 
all single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives 
(such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long running operations.
```

Comment: Whats the exception? Define getting stuck

Comment: The progress bar doesn't move and the main form gets un-responsive. I added the exception to the question because it is to long for a comment

Comment: What line crashes and whats the exception?

Comment: I added the exception to the question above because it is too long

Comment: Do not Dispose() the Backgroundworker from DoWork().

Comment: How do I do it thread safe ? only one thread (the background worker) touches it...

Comment: How many files/lines are there? You are probably drowning the messagepump with progress-changes. Disable the per-line reporting and try again.

Comment: I have about 60 files with thousands of rows in each file

Comment: Not your problem but calling `File.ReadAllLines(file)` just to discover how many lines are there, discarding the array returned and then starting a loop with a StreamReader to read the same data that you have already loaded with ReadAllLines doesn't seem to be very efficient.

Comment: I'll change that. But how can I solve the actual problem I have ?

Comment: Report when every file is done, not when every row is read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a small example of your program, trying to guess what it must do (https://github.com/anderson-rancan/stackoverflow_28798348, drag and drop 4 files to the groupbox, lorem?.csv), and there is a few things that you should consider:

- never try/catch a unknown exception, every exception or something you cannot deal with (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182137.aspx)
- when using a BackgroundWorker on a form, use the "sender" for references to it, it's a thread safe object to your method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx)
- maybe you are updating too fast your form, change your Invoke method to BeingInvoke, and do the update async (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3(v=vs.110).aspx)

So, just fixing that was possible to run it, like this:

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker bckw = (BackgroundWorker)sender; // Recommended way, thread safe

    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(saveFilePath))
        {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                btnBrowseSave.PerformClick();
            }));
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(saveFilePath))
        {
            if (dragEventArgs != null)
                files = (string[])dragEventArgs.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

            int filesCount = 0, rowsCount = 0;
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                filesCount++;
                double fileTotalLines = File.ReadAllLines(file).Length;

                this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    lblFileName.Text = "Loading file: " + file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                    lblTotalFiles.Text = "File " + filesCount + " of " + files.Length;
                })); // Invoke async, way too fast this...

                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(saveFilePath))
                    {
                        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                while (stopPosition > rowsCount)
                                {
                                    reader.ReadLine();
                                    rowsCount++;
                                } // why are you using that? it won't get TRUE

                                string email = reader.ReadLine().Trim();
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) && !dicEmails.ContainsKey(email))
                                {
                                    dicEmails.Add(email, null);
                                    writer.WriteLine(email);
                                }
                                rowsCount++;
                                stopPosition++;

                                bckw.ReportProgress((int)Math.Round(rowsCount * 100 / fileTotalLines, 0), (int)ProgressType.Row);
                                if (bckw.CancellationPending)
                                    return;
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                hadReadErrors = true;
                                throw; // Throw it again, or you won't know the Exception
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                bckw.ReportProgress(0, (int)ProgressType.Row);
                bckw.ReportProgress((filesCount * 100 / files.Length), (int)ProgressType.File);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        hadReadErrors = true;
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        bckw.Dispose();
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //try
    //{
    switch ((int)e.UserState)
    {
        case (int)ProgressType.Row:
            lblFileProgress.Text = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";
            if (e.ProgressPercentage <= fileProgressBar.Maximum)
                fileProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            break;
        case (int)ProgressType.File:
            lblTotalProgress.Text = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";
            totalProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            break;
    }
    //}
    //catch (Exception ex) { } // Don't catch everything
}
```

Finally, may I suggest another approach?
You're reading the file two times: one to get the number of lines, and another to read each line. Try to do this just once, you'll get a better result.